# Prove $\delta_{kl} + \frac{1}{3}\sum_{i,j}R_{ikjl}x^ix^j$ defines a metric

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $g$ be a bilinear form on $V$ over $\Bbb{R}$, which is defined in terms of basis as :

$$\delta_{kl} + \frac{1}{3}\sum_{i,j}R_{ikjl}x^ix^j$$

Where $R_{ikjl}$ is the algebraic curvature tensor, prove it defines a Riemannian metric when $|x|$ is small.

(Combined with the fact that Taylor expansion of the metric is $$\begin{equation}
g_{ij} = \delta_{ij} + \frac{1}{3} R_{ikjl} \,x^kx^l + \mathcal{O}(|x|^3) 
\end{equation}
$$

this shows the linear part of the Talor expansion is again a metric which is an approximation of the original metric.）

The symmetry of the bilinear form $g$ due to symmetry of the curvature tensor, only needs to prove it's positive definite, that is we need to prove $$R_{ikjl}x^kx^lv^iv^j \ge 0$$

This seems not very obvious for me, I know we must use the symmetry of the curvature tensor, in particular the Jacobi identity for $R_{ikjl}$.

Comment: Don't you have any assumption on the curvature tensor? Where does this come from?

Comment: I suspect this result also, since we don't know to sign of $R_{ikjl}$ there is no reason to let $R_{ikjl}x^kx^lv^iv^j \ge 0
$

Comment: This comes from a exercise problem @Didier

Comment: This indeed defines a metric on a region where $|x|$ is small enough since positive definite symmetric matrices form an open subset of the algebra of matrices, but I can't see how and why this would extend to all of $V$.

Comment: Oh sorry, I restate the exerise , which says this holds in some normal coordiante where $(U,(x^1,..,x^n))$ is the cooridnate chart

Comment: Since the norm of the matrix $\frac{1}{3}\sum_{i,j}R_{ikjl}x^ix^j
$ is small if $|x|$ is small, so it does not change the signature of the matrix correct? @Didier

Comment: You can write your candidate to be a metric as $Id + O(|x|^2)$, so that a continuity argument will show that it is positive definite for $|x|$ small enough